# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, python-3.x

Help me please!

Sorry about my english , i'm weak in english!

I am trying to visit this page `192.168.56.102 / project / BP / 4`, it shows me this msg error!
the same configurations of urls and views with other page it works fine.

```
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.102/project/BP/4
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Project : 
    path('', views.projects , name = 'project'),
    path('BP/<int:id_project>', views.tb_project , name='tb_project'),
    path('add/', views.add_project , name = 'add_project'),
    path('delete/p/<int:id_project>',views.delete_project , name='delete_project'),
    path('edit/<int:id_project>' , views.edit_project , name = 'edit_project'),
    #Zone Action : 
    path('zone/<int:id_project>/' , views.list_zones , name ='list_zone'),
    path('zone/add/<int:id_project>/' , views.add_ZoneAction , name = 'add_zone'),
    path('delete/z/<int:id_project>/<int:id_zone>',views.delete_zone , name='delete_zone'),
    path('zone/edit/<int:id_zone>' , views.edit_ZoneAction , name = 'edit_zone'),
]
```

views.py :

```
def tb_project(request,id_project):
    template ="project/bord_project.html"
    context = {}
    prj = get_object_or_404(project ,id = id_project)
    context["prj"] = prj
    return render(request, template ,context)
```

page.html

```
<a href="{% url 'tb_project' element.id %}"> 
<!-- element.id = 4 -->
```

the link is displayed correctly in the page : `192.168.56.102/project/BP/4`  but when I click to go to `bord_project.html` I see an error msg!

Page.html :  
list_tuple is context variable

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block contenu %}

    <div class="container">

        {% for elements in list_tuple  %}

        <div class="row" style="margin-top : 10px;">

            {% for element in elements %}

            <div class = "col-4">
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Projet
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">

                            {{ element.intitule }}
                        </h5>
                        <p class="card-text">

                            {{ element.description|truncatewords:7 }}
                        </p>
                        <a href="{% url 'tb_project' element.id %}" class="btn btn-info">

                            {# link #}
                            Plus &raquo;
                        </a> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">

                        {{ element.date }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

for the moment bord_project.html is blank

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block contenu %}
  {# blank for the moment #}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show `project/bord_project.html` instead of `page.html`.

Comment: thanks @Alasdair , I edit the post, and I add `project/bord_project` , `page.html`

Comment: In your view ```prj = get_object_or_404(project ,id = id_project)```, is the model called ```project```? It's probably ```Project```

Comment: The error message says `Reverse for ''`, but none of the `{% url %}` tags you have shown would cause that error. Perhaps the problem is in `base.html`

Comment: thanks @Pedro , no it's project , i forgit to set it in capitale

Comment: @Alasdair,  I use base.html in other page , and it's work

Comment: When you use `base.html` in the other page, the context is different so it might not cause the same error. Is there any more of the error message that you haven’t shown? Perhaps you forgot to save/commit/redeploy/restart the server, so you aren’t running the code above. None of the code you have posted would give that error, so I can’t help.

Comment: Thanks, @Alasdair .. finally i found the solution in  base.html file ..it about a part of code that was in comment
`{#  ...  <a class="nav-link tab" href="{% url '' %}"></a> ... #}`
Despite being in comment the server interprets this part of code and i do not khnow why!

Comment: That snippet should have been treated as a comment (as long as it was all on one line), so it shouldn’t have raised an error.

Comment: It was a comment of 7 line 
1- `{#`   2- `<ul class="nav nav-tabs">` 3- `<li class="nav-item first-item">` 4- `<a class="nav-link tab" href="{% url '' %}"></a>` 5-`</li>`  6- `</ul>`  7- `#}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe the issue is in any code that you have pasted. You should run a `$ grep -r -E "reverse|url" .` or similar search command to find any url resolutions that you might be missing.

Somewhere you have a `reverse[_lazy]` function call or `url` templatetag that is performing a bad lookup.

Make sure that any uses of the `url` templatetag are using quotes around the view name.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, the error was in the parent html file `base.html` , some of the code was in commantaire, and  the server does not ignore it